# Should "composer" and "printcomposer" be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Both terms seem to only be used for the QGIS Print Composer. I'd therefore suggest the following synonym:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/composer/synonyms

Comment: Seeing as only [two people](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/composer/topusers) have an answer score >= 5 in the `composer` tag, I suggest a moderator approve the synonym without having to wait for votes which will likely never come. (*[insert rant about synonym voting rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127459)*)

Comment: I agree with blah238

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The synonym has now been created. Thanks for your feedback!